# Problem when changing screen in native react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, native

I created an app in native react with typescript, installed the dependencies, and installed so many things trying to fix my issue

It seems that there is an undefined in some array of children to a module.

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from './components/screens/HomeScreen';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const Home = (props:any) =>
{
  return(
    <p>Hola</p>
  )
}
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Main Screen' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Hola"
          component={Home}
          options={{ title: 'asd Screen' }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: This is a [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) app, right? If so, you shouldn't be able to use `<p></p>`, I believe - React Native doesn't have any HTML elements...

Comment: You are absolutely right, that <p></p> was just a way to test if the error was from Stack.Navigation from react native web.
(And yes, from the web part it does run, by changing the Stack.Navigation to the component that returns <p>).